# Plotting an interaction in R - error not able to access "sj.setGeomColors."

Tags: r, statistics, package

Here is my code with the messages that I am recieving in R:

```
> library(sjPlot)

    Attaching package: ‘sjPlot’

    The following objects are masked _by_ ‘.GlobalEnv’:

    adjust_plot_range, sjp.int

    Warning message:
    package ‘sjPlot’ was built under R version 3.1.3
```

> library(sjmisc)

```
   Warning message:
   package ‘sjmisc’ was built under R version 3.1.3
```

> library(ggplot2)

```
   Warning message:
   package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.1.3
```

> data(efc)
>
> sjp.setTheme(theme = "539", axis.title.size = .85, axis.textsize = .85, legend.size = .8, geom.label.size = 3.5)
>
> fit <- lm(VC ~ Pvty * W)
>
> summary(fit)
>
> sjp.int(fit, type = "cond")

```
 Error: could not find function "sj.setGeomColors"
```

R is able to read regression formula "VC ~ Pvty * W", but for some reason is having trouble either accessing the correct package or some other issue displaying the graph. I need to graph interaction in R.

Answer (score 0):

See warning: `sjp.int` is already masked by your global Environment. You need to clear your workspace first, then it should work.

Also, compare both plotting types `type = "cond"` and `type = "eff"`.